# Java: References and GC

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm new in Java programming, and I somehow understand how references and Garbage Collector work, but I need some suggestions.

If (for example), I need to read from files, and I'm using a loop to go through each file and read the text from them, should I avoid doing something like:

(br is an instance of BufferedReader)

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filePath"));
```

So basically, each time as loop excecutes, ***br*** references to a new object of BufferedReader. Is this the wrong way of doing it? And if it is, what can I do to make it work more efficiently?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Full code:

```
  public int kerko(String folderName, String wantedWord) throws IOException{
   File file = new File(folderName);

   int count = 0;
   if(file.isDirectory()){
       File[] files = file.listFiles();
       for(File f: files){
           if(f.isFile() && f.getName().endsWith(".txt")){
               br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f.getAbsolutePath()));
               String line = br.readLine();
               while(line != null){
                   if(line.toLowerCase().contains(wantedWord)){
                        count++;
                   }

                   line = br.readLine();
               }   
               br.close();
           }
           count += kerko(f.getAbsolutePath(), wantedWord);
       }  
   }
   return count;
}
```

Comment: You could perhaps show more of your code. Whether this is ok or not depends on whether you remember to call .close() on your BufferedReader in an exception safe manner.

Comment: I edited and posted the whole code.

Comment: As @nos mentioned, the code containing the readLine should be in a try-catch block, and the br.close() should be in the finally section. Otherwise a read error will throw an exception and you will never close the reader.

Comment: There's not actually any other way to do it.  This is the right approach.  (Except maybe to use try-with-resources?)

Answer (score 1):

It's ok to instantiate BufferedReader's and FileReader's in this way.

After leaving `{ }` block these objects will be unreachable and later GC will collect them.

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely fine to assign multiple objects to the same variable one after another. The garbage collector knows which objects are no longer referenced.

My general advice concerning garbage collection: Unless you do some really advanced stuff, don't think about it. That's what the garbage collector is made for.